# Is there any way to get clients information when disconnecting from the server?

Tags: java, client

Is there any way to get clients information when disconnecting from the server like when client connect to the server we can get using .getCanonicalHostName(); is it possible to get host name when client is disconnected ?

Im developing chat server/client application ,can anyone can tell me how to get online clients list in a specific time, now im using a Treeset and put all the clients hostname to it,but when the disconnect from server ,i have no method to remove them from TreeSet becouse i cant track who is disconnected? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ?? If the client is disconnected then no more communication happens. Maybe you want to check which clients are still connected (or have shown activity in the last x time) and delete the others...

Comment: Sir plz can you tell me how to get that clients who are connected

Comment: @Roshan Where have you stored the Socket that represents the client ?

Comment: You could update your tree by checking if the hostName is one of the client connected, if not you simlpy remove it from your tree.

Answer (score 1):

Once your client is disconnected, its all over. You cant get any more information from them at all. You could get it while they are connected, store it, and use it after they disconnect, but once they are disconnected you cant get anything from them at all.

Its like if I walk to your front door and start a conversation with you and shortly there after leave. Then ten minutes later you say to the spot I was standing "how was your day?" Clearly Im not going to know you said that, so I wont be able to respond, and you wont know.

Comment: @ Dgrin91 - ya, i can understand sir , but i cant understand how to do that , that's the thing,

Comment: @Roshan what are you referring to when you say "that"

Comment: "store it, and use it after they disconnect"

Comment: Oh, just put it in a variable. `String s = inet.getCannonicalHostName;`

Comment: No No sir sorry if you misunderstand me , i can do that that means `String s = inet.getCannonicalHostName;` and im doing it when client is connect to server , the thing is i cant remove client when client disconnect from the server becouse , i cant find which client is disconnected ! sry if im disturbing you ! ;-(

Comment: @Roshan So wait... your question is how do you figure out if a specific client has disconnected?

Comment: @ Digin91 - yes , sir ... :-(